# Хром жалуется на неправильный mime type

Tags: html, content-type

Какая-то фигня с Хромом случилась. Запускаю свой сайт, сайт работает, но в консоли выдает два предупреждения:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=hhnkdzlc&CTID=ssaddon".
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://in.admedia.com/?id=OD8oNiE"
```

И ошибку

```
Uncaught Not a valid URL: http://www.mysite/
```

Проверил консоль при входе на  Хэшкод. Те же предупреждения, только без ошибки Uncaught Not a valid URL.
Что это может быть? Такого раньше не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хром предполагает один MIME type по расширению в url, а в ответе другой Content-Type. Абсолютно ничего страшного.

А с ошибкой не совсем понятно, в консоль это мог написать кто-угодно, например, какая-нибудь используемая библиотека.

UPD:
Комментарий *cy6erGn0m* навёл на мысль. Может быть, хром как большой любитель кеширования, в некоторых случаях запоминает content-type для url и удивляется тому, что он может поменяться?

Comment: Какому расширению в URL? Это вообще очень расплывчатое понятие. К тому же, здесь ведь нет никакого расширения, которое можно было бы интерпретировать как скрипт..

Comment: У jsp mime-type какой? Наверное, что-то типа application/*, хром это называет скриптом, видимо.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такое сообщение в Chrome и в FireFox пропало после того, как подставил минимизированный CSS (closure-stylesheets.jar). Подозреваю, что после удаления всех (русскоязычных) комментариев